# Short children's story about an android who thinks they're human who creates an android

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

The [Tomato Surprise](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/TomatoSurprise/Literature) TV Tropes page describes a story about an android who thinks they're human who creates an android.

> In a short story in a children's book, the protagonist is a young prodigy living in a high-tech city. For his next project, he decides to build an artificial human that mimics real humans as close as possible. He spends weeks designing and building it, and finally takes the artificial human to show the city's leader. The leader looks at him and admits the android shows some potential, but points out flaws such as the lack of tannable skin, or realistic emotions, or aging. When the protagonist fails to see how this is important, the leader has him strapped into a chair and shows him an old video of a group of old men watching a young boy eat. He reveals that these men are the last living humans. The boy is their first robot designed to replace them and is able to do all the things real humans can do. The leader is that boy. The protagonist realizes that all of the city's inhabitants are robots, including him. As he is being led away to have the last hour wiped from his memory (ignorance is bliss), he takes a look at his creation and, for the first time, sees just how *fake* it looks.

What is this story, who was the author, and in what children's book does this appear?